# Bootstrap- Create default "Please Choose Page" dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bootstrap template and would like a default "Please Choose Page" item to appear in the drop down menu when the menu adjusts for tablet and smartphone viewing. As far as I can tell, the existing script relating to the drop down is:

```
    $cjq(".dropdown").hover(
    function () {
        $cjq(this).addClass("open");
    },
    function () {
        $cjq(this).removeClass("open");
    }
    );

$cjq("<select />").appendTo(".buttons-container");
$cjq(".buttons-container select").addClass('nav-select');

$cjq(".nav-collapse a").each(function() {
    var el = $cjq(this);

    if (el.parent().hasClass("active")){
        $cjq("<option />", {
            "selected": "selected",
            "value"   : el.attr("href"),
            "text"    : el.html().replace(/<i>.*<\/i>/gi,'')
        }).appendTo(".buttons-container select");
    } else {
        $cjq("<option />", {
            "value"   : el.attr("href"),
            "text"    : el.html().replace(/<i>.*<\/i>/gi,'')
        }).appendTo(".buttons-container select");
    }
});

$cjq(".buttons-container select").change(function() {
    window.location = $cjq(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

I've tried integrating the following, but I'm not really familiar with javascript and cannot get it working:

```
    $("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Please choose page"
}).appendTo(".buttons-container select");
```

The development page [can be viewed here.](http://www.asam.edu.au/2013/)

If anyone has any pointers I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the option in the `select class="nav-select"`